# How to set highlighting of directories with added files to red/blue

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using PhpStorm 8.0.3 (on Windows, MacOs and Linux). I'm using GIT in my project. My remote server is through SSHFS.

I know option "**Show directories with changed descendants**". I've marked it. But when I'm adding new files (they are marked on red in project tree view), parents of these directories are not highlighted/marked (such directories have normal, white color). How can I change it?

Thanks.

Comment: Also, I have same problems with added files in Find in Path dialog. I want to treat my added files as my changed files (maybe have some custom scope with added and changed files).

Answer (score 2):

Please vote for [IDEA-138890](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-138890) to be notified on any updates